# EE 2.5.2 upgrade to EE 3.5.12 - Error

Tags: ee2, ee3, structure

[image]

I'm getting this error message after a fresh install update. Any one have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Upgrade structure module?

Comment: Please clarify your question... did this happen *during* an upgrade? The words "fresh install update" do not really make sense. Is it a fresh install of 2.5.2 that's just been updated? A fresh 3.5.12 install? What is going on?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I tried doing an upgrade from 2.5.2 to 3.5.12. It ended up causing a lot of errors. I am now importing content manually into 3.5.12 from a fresh install. It's working just fine. The website doesn't have too much content so it's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can add column 'updated' in exp_structure table or you can disable structure module extension during upgrade. Once upgrade will be done you can enable it and fix it's bugs.